# ubuntu freezes after login (even though driver installed)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login-screen

I've been dual booting my ubuntu 18.04 LTS with my external HDD. However, I keep getting stuck in a purple blank screen after login.

Ubuntu is working fine in my **desktop(GTX 1060)**, but having trouble in my **laptop(GTX 1060 maxQ)**.

I saw others handling this problem by installing the Nvidia driver, but I already had **nvidia-driver-440** installed(both recommended on my laptop and desktop).

But by seeing that **prime-select intel works**, I'm quite certain that there's a problem with the nvidia driver.

I want to fix this problem because I need to use my Graphics card for my project using CUDA. I would really appreciate any help(other than just reinstalling the nvidia driver, since it might cause the same problem again). Please feel free to leave any comments on solutions or anything to improve my poor question.

++ I don't know why, but when I connect another monitor with HDMI, the laptop screen is still stuck but shows well on the other monitor

Comment: and also blacklisting nouveau isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By connecting an external monitor via HDMI, I found out that nvidia wasn't detecting my internal laptop display.

So I dug in to this problem and found this post

[Internal laptop screen not detected when using Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver)

by replacing the xorg.conf configuration file to the original one solved the problem.