# Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect my laptop screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, display, external-monitor, nvidia-prime

After some investigation, I found this thread that had a solution. I downgraded my nvidia driver to 435 - and it solved the issue, I can now use HDMI screen, but my laptop screen now is black and unusable.

[Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230924/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-recognize-second-monitor/1231019#1231019?newreg=9678a7a6f0a64a0b9e0d175a6e5f6715)

> I downgraded to nvidia-435 driver, and it worked fine. Something didn't >get thoroughly vetted/tested with the 440 drivers. Just downgrade for now >and see if that helps.

Does anyone know how can I connect my laptop screen again?

my xrandr:

````
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93 ```
````

When I run `sudo prime-select intel` my laptop screen works and the HDMI doesn't, but when I run `sudo prime-select nvidia` my laptop screen doesn't work and the hdmi does.

Any ideas why is this? And how to have both of them working at the same time?

Comment: in system settings there is an option to select what screen you want to be acctive https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Appearance#PC

Comment: @trondhansen there is no such option on my settings.

Comment: sorry but it is on my desktop pc so i asumed it was the same on laptops,running ubuntu 20.04 and i know other versions of ubuntu has the option to change what screen to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal laptop screen not detected when using Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what happend to me was that for some reason, when I saved the nvidia-settings to the X file (/etc/X11/xorg.conf) configs only for the external monitor were added. As a result, after a reboot, only the external monitor was detected.

The NVIDIA X Server Settings software can be opened by running 'nvidia-settings' on the terminal.

As suggested by Kulfy, the solution was to delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf and do a reboot. Everything works again as expected.

See this [Internal laptop screen not detected when using Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver)

Comment: Thanks Emanoel, that solution worked out for me, after a lot of failed attempts with a bunch of purges and installs, that resulted in login screen loops, unbootable sessions and even Ubuntu startup freezing, awaiting for an external monitor for login screen to be shown.