# 18.04 | Cannot use the Laptop without external monitor [SOLVED]

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

I have a Laptop running the Ubuntu 18.04. At the beginning, I was using only the Laptop screen. And then, I tried to connect an external monitor via HDMI. At first, system couldn't detect the external monitor. I made some research and updated my GPU drivers. Recently, the second monitor is working fine, but the laptop screen is blank. And, I cannot see the laptop screen at the ***displays*** page. Unfortunately, I can no more use the Laptop screen by itself. I must always connect to an external monitor via HDMI. What do you think the problem is?

As if needed, system has an i7-8750H and a GTX1060 in it.

Here is a screenshot from the **additional drivers** page:
[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SZUd.png)

Here is a screenshot from **displays** page:
[Displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoKgD.png)

**EDIT:** I switched the GPU driver to *nouveau driver*. Now I can use the Laptop screen and system can detect the external monitor but not properly. Here is screenshot from *Displays* page:[Displays after *nouveau* driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TM7f.png)

- If I mirror the screens, I can only see the cursor on the external
  screen. The Laptop screen works properly.
- If I try to use only the Laptop screen, no problem occurs.
- If I try to use only the external screen, I can see all windows but cannot click on them. The interesting thing is that I can move the mouse. How the hack, lol
- If I try to join the screens, I can only see a black screen on the external monitor and Laptop screen works properly.

**EDIT 2:** I discovered something new.

- If I de-activate external GPU by calling `sudo prime-select intel`, the external screen goes black and I only have the Laptop screen. After then, I can only see the "Built in Display" settings in the *Displays* page.
- Same happens after activating the external GPU. I call `sudo prime-select nvidia` and then Laptop screen freezes with a blank screen on it. It also has the cursor at the bottom right corner. But, I cannot switch to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar problem in the site. The guy solved the problem by removing configuration file under `xorg`. Here is the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver):

```
cd /etc/X11
sudo rm xorg.conf
sudo cp xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original xorg.conf
reboot
```