# Laptop display missing from settings and screen black

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

So I had everything set up how I wanted, 2 Dell external monitors with my laptop screen turned off.

Come to my computer and the laptops display is on but black, and one of my Dell screen is off. I go to my display settings and i see this.

[image]

so I tried rebooting, no change.

I unplug the two external monitors and laptop screen is still black.

One of the external monitors i HDMI plugged into a HDMI to USB-c which goes into laptop, i just plugged it in straight with HDMI and then 2 displays return, i see this in the settings:

[image]

I'm pretty new to Linux and at a loss. I would at least like to be able to turn the laptop display off but it seems that Ubuntu is not recognizing my laptop display anywhere.

Also should mention that the same moniter-HDMI cable-HDMI to USB-c adapter connection is working fine on another windows laptop.

```
null@nullz:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 2400, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+1200 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Anything new installed or any settings changed?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.  Last installation was Kdenlive i believe, from Ubuntu software center. if it helps video card is NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: @ChuckSpadina did you get any solution, same problem for me too.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver

Comment: Sadly no, I really just feel like it was Nvidia sabotage. Went back to Windows, still want an answer though