# Ubuntu 20.04 laptop screen is blank, but monitors connected to HDMI and USB-C ports work

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display, amd-ryzen

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Windows/Ubuntu dual boot, with Ubuntu on an external SSD). A long time ago, I made changes such that my two external monitors (one with an HMDI cable and one with a USB-C to HDMI cable) work, but my laptop screen does not. This was fine before, but now I'd like to actually use Ubuntu without having to constantly connect to an external monitor.

The laptop screen is always blank with a single `_` in the top left. It seems I am able to press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F3` and the screen will change to the typical **non-GUI** login screen (even though I can already be "logged in" and working on the two external monitors). If relevant, all three screens (both external and laptop screen) work just fine on Windows.

The output of `xrandr` (with both external monitors connected) is below. I have tried both USB-C ports on my laptop and it seems they are tied to `DP-0` and `DP-2`. I am not sure what is tied to `DP-1` and `DP-3`.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3000 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected 1080x1920+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    59.94    50.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+371 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00 + 143.86*  119.98   119.88   100.00    59.94    50.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is the output of `lshw -C video`:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fe0-fdf irq:92 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:fc00000000-fdffffffff memory:fe00000000-fe01ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fe0-fdf iomemory:fe0-fdf memory:fe10000000-fe1fffffff memory:fe20000000-fe201fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
```

and the output of `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 525.147.05

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I've tried some of the things described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver), but sadly my laptop screen still does not work. I am *ideally* looking for a solution where I can use my laptop screen **and** my two external monitors, but if there's a solution where I can switch between each configuration quickly (laptop screen when away from home and external monitors when home), that would also work.